# Search and copy Files with certain file name but not file type?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I am trying to create a batch file that will copy files from various folder locations to an existed folder structure.

Here is what I have in mind

ROBOCOPY "\server\folder2010\AB*TXT" "C:\Folder\2010" NOT type: JPG

ROBOCOPY "\server\folder2011\AB*TXT" "C:\Folder\2011" NOT type: JPG

I want it to be able to search for the file 
AB*TXT within multiple sub directories but exclude files with that file name that has a different file type. I know in explorer I can search for the file by using AB**.TXT NOT type: JPG. Not sure how I would accomplish this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try help --> `robocopy /?`

one of the option is

```
/XF file [file]... :: eXclude Files matching given names/paths/wildcards.
```

that can be used like

```
robocopy <Source> <Destination> /xf *.jpg
```

if you wanna do text only and leave out jpg

```
robocopy <Source> <Destination> /E *.txt /xf *.jpg
```

Comment: Excellent, Thank you.